# How i can have the same xMin,yMin for vector files in Qgis 2.4

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system

i have a .shp file(polygon) in EPSG:2100 - GGRS87 / Greek Grid and an other .shp(points) in the same system(EPSG:2100 - GGRS87 ) but different xMin,yMin.

The first has xMin,yMin 583309.00,4152885.94 and the second xMin,yMin 25.1148,37.6185.

How  can i put them in the same xMin,yMin.

Comment: The latter dataset is probably in EPSG:4326.

Comment: ... or EPSG:4121 called `GGRS87` but in lonlat degrees.